# How to render D3 js graph using json in mvc3 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, d3.js

I am new in D3 js.most of the examples in gallery load data from TSV files.
but  I wanted to render line graph using json in mvc3 razor. below is code where i hard code my data.please let me know how to retrive dynamic data using json.

```
var data = [
    { "date": 0, "close": 0.3372 },
    { "date": 1, "close": 1.7 },
    { "date": 2, "close": 1.8 },
    { "date": 3, "close": 2.014 },
    { "date": 4, "close": 10.995 },
    { "date": 5, "close": 16.227 },
    { "date": 6, "close": 16.643 },
    { "date": 7, "close": 20.644 },
    { "date": 8, "close": 22.478 }
    ];



        var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
        width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;



        var x = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0, width]);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

        var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function (d) { return y(d.close); });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        console.log("here");


        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.date = parseInt(d.date);
            d.close = +d.close;
        });

        console.log("here2");

        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.close; }));

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .text("Request")
            .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Probability");

        svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", line);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create bar graph dynamically using d3 js in .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979089/how-to-create-bar-graph-dynamically-using-d3-js-in-net)

Comment: Please don't post you're question again. You have not replied to my comment made 21 hours ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979089

Comment: both question are different.In this question my data is hard code and i wanted to render it using json in mvc razor application.i am glad to say i have done it also..thanks